# Solution of differential lyapunov equation

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, matrix-equations, periodic-functions

How would I solve for following, else any implemented algorithms or solvers in matlab (even ways to solve it) for Lyapunov differential equation of form:

$$P'(t) + A(t)^TP(t) + P(t)A(t) + Q(t) = 0,$$

where $Q(t)> 0$, with $P(t)$ being symmetric periodic positive definite, $A(t)$ is linearized dynamics of the system.

Comment: Hi and welcome in MSE! Could you please edit your question and insert your thoughts/tries on it. This will enhance your chance of getting an answer. Moreover, this will help other members to understand where is exactly your problem.

Comment: I changed the [complex-dynamics tag](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/complex-dynamics/info) to [dynamical-systems](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamical-systems/info) and edited your question for formatting. You can read more about mathematical typesetting on this site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/). I'm not sure what $P(t)_{\text dot}$ is supposed to mean, though, so you might need to improve that.

Comment: I think the equation should write $\frac{d}{dt}P(t)+A^T(t)P(t)+P(t)A^T(t)+Q(t)=0$.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy So "dot" is derivative with respect to time? I suspected that but was thrown off by $A'$, which I also figured should be a derivative. But you're saying $A'$ denotes the transpose, which makes sense the way it is used.  Maybe $A(t)^T$ makes more sense, though?  I do feel that there should be a transpose on only one of the $A$s.

Comment: @MarkMcClure I did my share of studying Lyapunov equations (both discrete and continuous), so the equation came naturally=) As per $A^T(t)$ vs $A(t)^T$, this, in my opinion, is a matter of taste - I have not encountered yet a situation where one notation would be objectively better than the other.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy the equation in my question is right, and exactly the way it is mentioned in several papers.

Comment: @Surb the ways I have solved it as mentioned in 'Lyapunov Matrix Equation in System Stability and Control' Zoran Gajic et. al. To be more definite Algorithm 4.1 in Chapter 4: Differential and Difference Lyapunov Equation. I want to verify and solve with more contemporary solve or algorithms if available and see what is the difference, stability and precision. Regards, Parantap

Comment: @MarkMcClure Yes, dot represents the derivative with respect to time. As it is differential lyapunov equation. The solution of the P(t) is dependent on time and state the systems is going through. :)

Answer (score 5):

Suppose that $A$ is constant. Let us take $$P(t)=\exp(-tA^T)R(t)\exp(-tA),$$ where $R(t)$ is some matrix. We can write the derivative of $P$:
$$P'(t)=-A^TP(t)-P(t)A+\exp(-tA^T)R'(t)\exp(-tA) = -A^TP(t)-P(t)A-Q(t).$$
Now we have $$R'(t)  =  - \exp(tA^T)Q(t)\exp(tA),$$ which is easy to solve.

This method can be generalized to  $A=A(t)$, but it will require strong hypothesis on $A(t)$: we will need that $A(t_1)A(t_2)=A(t_2)A(t_1)$ for all $t_1$ and $t_2$.

Comment: could you point me to somewhere where the time-dependent A(t) is considered?

Answer (score 1):

The analytical solution to this problem is

\begin{equation}
P(t) = \int_0^t \Phi^T(\tau,t)Q(\tau)\Phi(\tau,t)d\tau
\end{equation}
where $\Phi(\tau,t)$ is the [state transition matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-transition_matrix) from time $t$ to time $\tau$ associated with the linear system $\dot{x}(t) = A(t) x(t)$.  (In your case, $A(t)$ is coming from a linearization.)  You may or may not be able to obtain a closed-form representation of the state transition matrix $\Phi(\tau,t)$. Sometimes, an analytical expression for $\Phi(\tau,t)$ can be easily obtained (e.g. in the linear time-invariant case, $\Phi(\tau,t)=e^{A(\tau-t)}$).  Even if you do not have an exact expression for $\Phi(\tau,t)$, you can still verify that this form is correct by differentiation.  Since $t$ appears both in the upper limit and within the integral, you need to use [Leibniz's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).  You also need to use the fact that $\frac{d}{dt} \Phi(\tau,t) = -\Phi(\tau,t)A$.  Substitution completes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, (1) proposed novel formulations of solution algorithms for differential matrix equations based on an $LDL^{T}$ decomposition that keep the computations in real arithmetic.

According to the authors, the proposed methods are a more practical alternative for large-scale problems arising in applications, and the numerical results from the paper show better performance of the proposed methods compared to earlier formulations.

Albeit the methods in the paper focus more on the differential Riccati equation, they naturally restrict to the differential Lyapunov equation:

> However, all our methods and techniques naturally restrict to the
>   differential Lyapunov equation (DLE) (see comments in Section 2.2). A
>   more detailed explanation and extensive numerical experiments for the
>   DLE will be presented elsewhere to keep the presentation within usual
>   page limits.

(1): Lang, Norman; Mena, Hermann; Saak, Jens (September 2015). "On the benefits of the $LDL^{T}$ factorization for large-scale differential matrix equation solvers". Linear Algebra and its Applications **480**: 44–71. [doi:10.1016/j.laa.2015.04.006](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379515002219).