# Is there a closed form solution to the matrix differential equation $\dot X=AX+XA^T - K$?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, matrix-equations

Is there a closed form solution the matrix differential equation

$\dot X = AX + XA^T - K $

for example when
$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$
and
$K = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

In general $A$ is square and $K$ is positive semi-definite.

As far as I understand the equation:

$\dot X = AX + XA^T$

has the closed form solution

$X(t) = e^{At}Ce^{tA^T}$

Can this be extended to $\dot X = AX + XA^T - K $?

These are similar questions, but do not answer the closed form solution question:

[On the solution of one matrix differential equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2751645/on-the-solution-of-one-matrix-differential-equation/2751700#2751700)

[Solution of differential lyapunov equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1183641/solution-of-differential-lyapunov-equation)

Answer (score 3):

This is a linear non-homogeneous differential equation, so the standard techniques apply.  The catch is that since it is not presented in the usual form $\dot x = Ax + b$, we would either have to put this equation into that form or do things in a coordinate-free fashion.

We can reframe this problem in the standard presentation using the [vectorization operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)).  In particular: if we define $x = \operatorname{vec}(X), k = \operatorname{vec}(K) \in \Bbb R^{4 \times 1}$ and vectorize both sides of the differential equation, then your differential equation becomes
$$
\dot x = (I \otimes A + A \otimes I)x - k \implies\\
\dot x = 
\pmatrix{0&1&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0} x - \pmatrix{0\\0\\0\\1}
$$

This differential equation has a closed form solution and can be solved using standard methods.  To get the answer to the original equation, it suffices to "unvectorize" our general solution $x(t)$ to the above differential equation.

---

*Flawed earlier attempt:*

We can rewrite your differential equation as
$$
\dot X -AX - XA^T = -K
$$
This is a linear differential equation since the map $X \mapsto \dot X - AX - XA^T$ is linear.  Your solution $X_h(t) = Ce^{At}e^{tA^T}$ solves the homogeneous problem, $\dot X - AX - XA^T = 0$.  It now suffices to find a particular solution to the equation 
$$
\dot X -AX - XA^T = -K
$$

Taking $X = t^2P + tQ + R$ as our Ansatz, we find that
$$
\dot X - AX - XA^T = -K \implies\\
2tP + Q - A(t^2P + tQ + R) - (t^2P + tQ + R)A^T = -K \implies\\
-t^2[AP + PA^T] + t[2P - AQ - QA^T] + [Q + K - AR - RA^T]
$$
In other words, it suffices to find matrices $P,Q,R$ satisfying the system of equations
$$
\begin{cases}
AP + PA^T = 0\\
AQ + QA^T = 2P\\
AR + RA^T = Q + K
\end{cases}.
$$
For such $P,Q,R$, we can write our general solution as $X(t) = Ce^{At}e^{tA^T} + t^2P + tQ + R$.

Comment: From a more thorough look it appears that there are no $P,Q$ satisfying the equation for your particular $A$ and $K$, which means that a different Ansatz is required.  I suspect that adding a quadratic term should be sufficient.

Comment: Having "fixed" the problem, I appear to still be stuck.  Perhaps since $X \mapsto AX + XA^T$ is a nilpotent operator with order $4$, we should be introducing a quartic term.  I think that the polynomial approach should work, though

Comment: It appears this still leads to coefficient matrices $P,Q,R$ with a structure like 
$\begin{bmatrix}
c_{11} & c_{12} \\
-c_{12} & 0
\end{bmatrix}$
which also repeats for higher order $t$, or am I mistaken?

Comment: I think you're right. I'll try a different approach

Comment: I've added an approach that I know will work (but that I don't like as much)

Comment: So the vectorized matrix is defective, (eigenvalue 0 with multiplicity 4, and eigen vectors  $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$. So probably an approach like the one described in [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=40lTNlgaqig) is required.

Comment: Something like that.  Keep in mind, however, that the video is about a homogeneous linear differential equation and your equation is non-homogeneous. Your closed-form solution is the solution to the homogeneous differential equation.